# Xemacs Custom Syntax Highlighting

Tags: elisp, syntax-highlighting, xemacs

I have some .el files that my professor had created for a VM Linux machine that he gave us. I have just installed Linux on an older laptop and I installed XEmacs on it. However I'm having trouble with XEmacs using the .el files. It won't add any highlighting, tab width of 4 or anything.

I put all the .el files in .xemacs/ directory.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I'll also include the code from the .el files so you can all see it.

As far as my OS I'm running 64-bit Fedora 18. Spherical Cow. MOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!

Thanks for the help everyone!

init.el file:

```
;; Turn on line and column numbers
(line-number-mode 1)
(column-number-mode 1)
;;-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
;; Python
;;-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'turn-on-font-lock t)
;;-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
;; C/C++
;;-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.C\\'" . c++-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.h\\'" . c++-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'turn-on-font-lock t)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'turn-on-font-lock t)
(setq c-default-style "bsd"
  c-basic-offset 4)

(defun my-c++-mode-hook ()

;;switch/case:  make each case line indent from switch
  (c-set-offset 'case-label '+)

;; Automatically indent after a newline (like vi)
(local-set-key '[(return)] 'newline-and-indent)

;; Tab sanity: match the C indent, but don't insert new tabs (use spaces)
  (setq tab-width 4)
  (setq indent-tabs-mode nil))

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my-c++-mode-hook)

;;-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
;; LaTeX
;;-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
;;(setq auto-mode-alist (append '(("\\.tex$"  . LaTeX-mode)) auto-mode-alist))
;;(require 'tex-site)
;;(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
;;  '(lambda()
;;     (load-file "~/.xemacs/my-latex.el")  ; load these LaTeX preferences
;;     ))

;;-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
;; Abbreviations
;;-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
;;(setq-default abbrev-mode t)
;;(setq save-abbrevs t)
;;(setq abbrev-file-name "~/.xemacs/my-abbreviations.el"
;;(if (file-readable-p abbrev-file-name)
;;  (read-abbrev-file abbrev-file-name)
;;  )
```

custom.el file:

```
(custom-set-variables)
(custom-set-faces)

(setq minibuffer-max-depth nil)
```

my-abbreviations.el file:

```
(define-abbrev-table 'text-mode-abbrev-table '(
  ("\\a" "\\alpha" nil 0)
 )
)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Rather than say "it doesn't work" tell us precisely what keys you hit, which behavior you expected, and what you got instead.

Comment: These .el files are supposed to add syntax highlighting for multiple languages, auto indentation, tab width of 4, etc. 

I put these .el files in the .xemacs directory where xemacs should then read them and add all of the syntax highlighting and such. But none of it appears. It's just plain black text with no highlighting, etc. 

How do I get xemacs to add the highlighting and other things as specified in the .el files.

Comment: Nothing jumps at me.  Have you tried it with Emacs instead?

Comment: Have you tried to (load-file "/path/to/something.el") these files directly?  XEmacs will not automatically load these files just because they're in your ~/.xemacs.